# How to remove a string within a list item in python

Tags: python, list

On a project I am currently getting returned a list as follows:

```
[u'40620', u'00700', u'24150', u'11700']
```

How can I edit the list so it is returned just integer values:

```
[40620, 00700, 24150, 11700]
```

Thanks!

Comment: `00700` is not a valid integer value.

Answer (score 2):

Use a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and [`int`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int):

```
>>> lst = [u'40620', u'00700', u'24150', u'11700']
>>> [int(x) for x in lst]
[40620, 700, 24150, 11700]
>>>
```

Comment: The Py3 example would work in Python 2 as well, and is recommended

Comment: @michel-slm - Eh, why not.  I'll let Cygwinnian have the `map` solution. :)

Answer (score 1):

Simple one liner:

```
results = map(int, results)
```